# How do I take a screenshot of a page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I want to write an extension which captures an area of a page. I know how to write basic extensions, but I don't know of there's an API or a work-around for this. Where do I start? What should I look at? Are there APIs for this or can it be done by playing around with the canvas?

Comment: Have you tried to use http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab ?

Comment: Definitely duplicate of that. Thanks!